# Hallar la sumatoria de los números pares hasta un número x javascript

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

Necesito hacer una función tome como parámetro un numero X y que devuelva el total de la suma de todos los números que son pares del 0 al X.

> Esto hace 0+2+4+6+8+10+.....X.

Pero no se que mas me falta agregar, por que esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora y no me devuelve lo que pido:

```js
function sumaDeLosParesDel0Al(x){
      var suma = 0
      for (var i=1; i<x; i++){
        if (i%2 == 0) {
          suma += i
        }
      }
      return suma
    }
    
console.log(sumaDeLosParesDel0Al(4));
```

Comment: También debes indicar cuál es el problema o mensaje de error textual que tiene el código que has incluido.

Comment: esta bien tranquilo, te falta un `=` en `for (var i=1; i<x; i++)` deberia ser `for (var i=1; i<=x; i++)`, eso es todo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

te falta un `=` en

```
for (var i=1; i<x; i++)
```

debería ser

```
for (var i=1; i<=x; i++)
```

eso es todo

```js
function sumaDeLosParesDel0Al(x){
  var suma = 0
  for (var i=1; i<=x; i++){
    if (i%2 == 0) {
      suma += i
    }
  }
  return suma
}

console.log(sumaDeLosParesDel0Al(5));
```

Comment: coloco la respuesta como wiki de la comunidad ya que la solución de un problema tan simple no amerita recibir puntos por votación.

Answer (score 7):

Te propongo este algoritmo que no utiliza bucles.

Existen exactamente `N/2` cantidad de números pares entre `2` y `N`, cuando `N` es par, y `(N-1)/2` números pares cuando `N` es impar.

La suma del menor (`N_0`) de esos números pares con el el mayor de ellos (`N_n`), es igual a la suma del siguiente número par mayor que el menor (`N_1`) con el número par anterior al mayor (`N_n-1`).

Esto es una [progresión aritmética](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progresi%C3%B3n_aritm%C3%A9tica), la cual se traduce en la siguiente fórmula:

```
const suma = n*(min + max)/2;
```

Donde `n` es el número de pares que hay entre `0` y `N`, `min` sería en este caso `2` y `max` valdrá `N` cuando es par y `N-1` cuando es impar.

Así el algoritmo puede quedar de la siguiente forma:

```js
const sumaSoloPares = (numero) => {
  if (numero < 2) return 0;
  if (numero < 4) return 2;
  const numOfPares = Math.floor(numero/2);
  const min = 2;
  const max = numero%2 === 0 ? numero : numero - 1;
  const suma = ((min + max)*numOfPares)/2;
  return suma;
}

console.log(sumaSoloPares(10));
console.log(sumaSoloPares(20));
console.log(sumaSoloPares(1345));
console.log(sumaSoloPares(15));
console.log(sumaSoloPares(40));
console.log(sumaSoloPares(41));
```

Espero que esto aporte otra visión de la resolución del problema.

Comment: ¡ Carajo ! Has publicado mientras estaba editando la mia :-(

Comment: De hecho puede ser mejor tu respuesta usando memoizacion

Comment: Muchachos se que les apasionan los algoritmos, pero creo que se están complicando mucho para un problema que puede resolverse en una sola linea.

Comment: bueno igual +1 por la explicación.

Answer (score 3):

Haciendo `i = i + 2` en lugar de `i++` hacemos la mitad de las iteraciones, y no necesitamos chequear que sean pares porque siempre serán pares.

```js
function sumaDeLosParesDel0Al(x){
    var suma = 0
    for (var i=0; i<=x; i = i + 2){      
        suma += i
    }
    return suma
  }
  
console.log(sumaDeLosParesDel0Al(40));
```

Answer (score 3):

En realidad, no es necesario realizar ningún *bucle*; podemos, simplemente, utilizar la función genérica de suma de [progresiones aritméticas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progresi%C3%B3n_aritm%C3%A9tica):

> SUMA = ( n * ( start + end ) ) / 2;

Siendo

- `n` el número del último elemento de la progresión.
- `start` el primer valor de la progresión.
- `end` el último valor de la progresión.

```js
function suma( start, end, n ) {
  return ( n * ( start + end ) ) / 2;
}

console.log( 'suma 1 ... 5:', suma( 1, 5, 5 ) );
console.log( 'suma 2 ... 6:', suma( 2, 6, 3 ) );
console.log( 'suma 1 ... 49:', suma( 1, 49, 49 ) );
```

Por lo que buscar la suma todos los números pares desde `2` hasta `X` es bastante sencillo:

```js
function suma( start, end, n ) {
  return ( n * ( start + end ) ) / 2;
}

function sumaPares( end ) {
  if( end < 2 ) { return 0; }
  if( end == 2 ) { return 2; }
  if( end & 1 ) { --end }

  return suma( 2, end, end / 2 );
}

console.log( 'suma 2 ... 6:', sumaPares( 6 ) );
console.log( 'suma 2 ... 10:', sumaPares( 10 ) );
console.log( 'suma 2 ... 11:', sumaPares( 11 ) );
```

Realizamos un par de comprobaciones para evitar resultados *curiosos*, y llamamos a `suma( )` con los valores adecuados :-)

Comment: Rayos, pensamos lo mismo casi al mismo tiempo. XDDD

Comment: De hecho puede ser mejor tu respuesta usando memoizacion (comentario++)

Comment: @JackNavaRow Ummmm.... no se, una función no-recursiva, de cálculo rápido ...  no estoy seguro de que merezca la pena *cachear* el resultado ...